# Symfony 3. KnpMenuBundle свой шаблон

Tags: symfony2, symfony3

Сейчас у меня меню сделано так

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li><a href="{{ path('nvbs_accident_homepage') }}">Серьезные аварии</a></li>
    <li><a href="{{ path('conversion_homepage') }}">Конвертация</a></li>
    <li><a href="{{ path('arfs_homepage') }}">aRFS</a></li>
</ul>
```

Хочу теперь для построения меню использовать KnpMenuBundle.
Меню выводится, но вот только не понятно, как сделать свой шаблон.

Answer (score 0):

Вы можете создать свой шаблон, а потом его привязать к меню, как показано ниже:

```
{{ knp_menu_render('название меню', {'template': 'AcmeBundle:Menu:knp_menu.html.twig'}) }}
```

Comment: По какому пути должен быть размещен этот шаблон?
пишу
    {{ knp_menu_render('AppBundle:MenuBuilder:mainMenu', {'currentClass': 'active', 'template': 'AppBundle:Menu:knp_menu.html.twig'}) }}
Шаблон размещаю в app/Resource/views/Menu/knp_menu.html.twig
При загрузке страницы получаю
Unable to find template "AppBundle:Menu:knp_menu.html.twig"